# Mysql: How can I name a subselect in a join to avoid joining identical subselects?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like:

```
select * from (select ... ) t1 join (select ... ) t2 on t1._ = t2._
```

where the join subselects are identical.  Is there an easy way to name this select so that I can use it both times?  I tried this:

```
select * from (select ... ) t1 join t1 t2 on t1._ = t2._
```

but it gave an error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cost of acquiring the rows in your subselect is significant, you may consider storing the intermediate result in a temporary table and then reference that twice in your select.
But you better measure this, because it also costs to store the intermediate result...

Can you share your query? Maybe you don't need to reference it twice after all?

Comment: Each of the subselects was doing a join, so I actually just factored it out into a series of joins instead.  Ultimately, I don't have to reference it twice, thanks for the lead ; )

Answer (score 1):

```
  CREATE VIEW MyCommonSelect (Col1, Col2. . .) AS
      SELECT Col1, Col2. . .
```

Depending on exactly what your query looks like, you may be able to name the subqueries internally, but something like this tends to indicate that the subquery represents database logic that (in my opinion — others disagree) deserves its own name.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only simply *writing* the query; there's no performance value because the view references are will be executed independently of one another (doesn't change if using a CTE, if it were supported).  A view is just a macro for the query...

Comment: Certainly.  It didn't occur to me that the OP was looking for a speed optimization.  In fact, it's possible that (depending on the view and the product used) that interposing a view could possibly cause a decrease in performance.

Comment: Yeah actually I am doing it for performance reasons.  Is this the only option, do I just need to execute the select twice?